# Are all AMD OE box fans the same within each series?

Tags: cpu, fan, heatsink

I'm considering upgrading my old, repurposed HTPC, which has an A4-5300, with an A8-5500. Both APUs are Virgo "Trinity" series, socket FM2 APUs, both had retail box versions, so I'm wondering if the fan and heatsink would have been the same from AMD.

Comment: Eh. This is one of those situations where I think focusing on your specific hardware in the title would be better than the more general option. Also - what sockets are these?

Comment: AMD and Intel typically didn’t chnage their heat sinks.  Specifics would be required to answer this question though

Comment: I'm confused. Are the specifics not visible, somehow? I have the exact APUs listed. Replacing an A4-5300 with an A8-5500.

Answer (score 0):

They're the same *socket* so *physically* as far as the socket footprint is concerned the fans should be interchangable as far as the socket is concerned.

A [*quick* bit of research](http://www.silentpcreview.com/amd-phenom-coolers) suggests that they used the same heatsink as the previous generation and they had different models based on TDP (for AM3+) . With the same generation, and similar TDPs, they should be the same heatsinks.

As they're the same socket, they should be cross compatible.